# If else program

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a problem with my last if-else statement. It keeps telling me "else without if"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DartBallGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the lucky dart ball game");
        System.out.println("Enter the dimension of your square board: ");
        double SideSize = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the radius of your dart ball, your radius has to be between a range of 1-" + SideSize / 3);
        double radius = input.nextDouble();
        if (radius > SideSize / 3) {
            radius = SideSize / 3;
            System.out.println("Your radius can't be greater than " + SideSize / 3 + " Your new radius is " + SideSize / 3);
        }


        int computersguess = 0;

        //Make a guess
        System.out.println("Let's play, create your own chance");
        System.out.println("Pick a number between 10 and 99");
        int playersguess = input.nextInt();

        if (playersguess < 99 && playersguess > 10)
            computersguess = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            int computersguess2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            System.out.println("My guess is " + computersguess + computersguess2);
        else
        System.out.println("Your number is not between 10 and 99, please reset game");
}
}
```

How do I correct the if-else issue?

Comment: You are missing the brackets on the last if condition

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, it is very safe every time to enclose if, else with braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using braces. Java is not python, and white space is not semantically meaningful. The only time you can use an `if / else` without braces is if the body is exactly one (or less) lines. And, in general, I recommend you never omit the braces (even when they are optional).

```
if (playersguess < 99 && playersguess > 10) {
    computersguess = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    int computersguess2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    System.out.println("My guess is " + computersguess + computersguess2);
} else {
    System.out.println("Your number is not between 10 and 99, please reset game");
}
```